# dojo tab container in Notes 9

Tags: dojo, dijit.layout, lotus-notes

Had an application that I worked on a year or two ago that contained a dojo tab container on a Notes Form (8.5.0) My client says that the application does not work since upgrading to Notes 9.0. When I run it on Notes 9.0 the content of the tabs all display but no tabs - pretty ugly. So I created a new form and added this to the form

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer" style="width: 400px; height: 100px;" tabStrip="true">
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="My first tab" selected="true">
    Lorem ipsum and all around...
  </div>
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="My second tab">
    Lorem ipsum and all around - second...
  </div>
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="My last tab">
    Lorem ipsum and all around - last...
  </div>
</div>
```

the form has nothing on it but this as pass through HTML. When I view it in a web client I see the content of the three tabs but no tabs to select. Is there something in N/D 9 that breaks the dojo tab container? and if so is there a work around?

Answer (score 0):

When I did the Domino 9 install I did an uninstall then an complete new install. Therefore previous versions of dojo were removed. When 9 installs it instals dojo 1.8.1 my code was pointing to an older version. Changed the HTMLHeader to:

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.8.1/dojo/dojo.js\" djConfig=\"parseOnLoad: true\"></script>
<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.8.1/dijit/themes/nihilo/nihilo.css\"/>
```

and now the tab table works fine.